# What are words called when they can be made from the sounds of letter names?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example:

- Icy → IC
- Excel → XL
- Easy →  EZ*

---

* This spelling is based upon the U.S.A's. more recent pronunciation of the letter [Z](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/z?q=Z), which is /ziː/, rather than the British style /zed/. Compare with the pronunciation of [easy](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/easy_1?q=easy), which is /iːzi/ in both regions. See: O.A.L.D.

Comment: I have heard this called "textspeak", as it is used to save characters when writing texts. But "textspeak" also covers "pls" for "please", which I don't think matches your question.

Comment: @AndyT These examples could all come under textspeak I think.  The "rules" are pretty vague.

Comment: Hmm. EZ is pronounced E-zed.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Only by wilfully pedantic British people, surely.

Comment: I recall a series of cartoons about this ... I M N D L F 8 R

Comment: Consider using 'rebus', maybe qualified as 'letter rebus'

Comment: William Steig wrote a book full of these In 1968 called CDB!  ... S I CDB.  ESABZB. BCNU. IF2P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a word is called a [**gramogram**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramogram), also spelled *grammagram*, or letteral word. They are a subset of [rebuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus), as Stefan mentioned.

Wikipedia specifically describes a gramogram as

> a letter or group of letters which can be pronounced to form one or more words

This may seem to indicate that only the combinations of letters may be called gramograms, but three ([1](http://www.highlightpress.com.au/gramograms.html), [2](http://www.audreydeal.co.uk/testlink), [3](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/grammagrams)) references on the page use gramogram to describe the words themselves.

Note that neither spelling of gramogram appears in the OED and only draw just over 5000 Google results combined (see [*gramogram* results](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=gramogram&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8); [*grammagram* results](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=grammagram&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)). So it does not appear to be a widely recognized term.

However, I did find two relevant results used in books, both by Rod L. Evans

- [*Tyrannosaurus Lex: The Marvelous Book of Palindromes, Anagrams, and Other Delightful and Outrageous Wordplay*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bVH4YNnJQCYC&pg=PT72&dq=grammagram&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3oNL5wMXVAhUBUWMKHVk_ClYQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=grammagram&f=false)
- [*Thingamajigs and Whatchamacallits: Unfamiliar Terms for Familiar Things*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8hWqD8iG0n4C&pg=PT147&dq=grammagram&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3oNL5wMXVAhUBUWMKHVk_ClYQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=grammagram&f=false)

Answer (score -2):

They are technically **[abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation)**.  You could also call them a form of **[sensational spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling)** - "the deliberate spelling of a word in an incorrect or non-standard way for special effect".  This would apply if used in the name of a product, for example, like "EZ-Fit": https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ez-fit

Comment: Not close enough for an 'answer'. AndyT shows above how such a response can be made. He correctly used a comment as 'textspeak' is a hypernym rather than a strict equivalent.  _Sensational spelling_ has been covered before, and as for abbreviations ...