# What's the word for using the names of letters and numbers to sound out a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, LXS = Alexis, or RTQL8N = articulatin'.
I seem to recall there being a word for this.

Comment: That's called a [**Gramogram**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404625/what-are-words-called-when-they-can-be-made-from-the-sounds-of-letter-names) <- duplicate

Comment: Thanks, @DecapitatedSoul. I knew it had to be here, I could not find that question, no matter how I phrased the search.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [phonemic orthography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonemic_orthography) :

> - an orthography (system for writing a language) in which the graphemes (written symbols) correspond to the phonemes (significant spoken sounds) of the language.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: No; OP is looking for the diversion; I remember that turning a calculator display upside-down was often involved.